# На обзорной странице ru.SO отсутствует перевод для привилегии отрицательного голоса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

[image: Vote down (costs 1 rep on answers)]

Обведенная часть по-прежнему на английском языке.

Comment: @Scimonster Looks like Tim did migrate the older questions, so I'm migrating this one as well.